# R to ignore NULL values

Tags: r

I have 2 vector in R, but some of the values in both are marked as "NULL".

I want R to ignore "NULLS", but still "acknowledge" their presence because of indexes ( I´m using intersect and which function).

I have tried this:

```
for i in 1:length(vector)
    if vector=="NULL"
        i=i+1
    else
        'rest of the code'
```

Is this a good approach? The algorithm is running, but vector are very large.

Comment: It might be more instructive if you post the 'rest of the code'. There may be different treatments for different examples. As other have said, you should clarify whether these "NULL"s are `NULL`s or whether they are character strings that you think are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should change "NULL" for NA, which is R's native representation for NULL values. Then many functions have ways of dealing with NA values, such as na.action option... You shouldn't call your vector 'vector' since this is a reserved word for the class.

```
yourvector[yourvector == "NULL"] <- NA
```

Also you shouldn't add 1 to i in your if, just do nothing:

```
for (i in 1:length(yourvector)) {
    if (!is.na(yourvector[i])) {
        #rest of the code
    }
}
```

Also tell what you wanna do. You probably don't need a for.

Comment: editing original. Thanks, I´m newbie...
In short, I want to calculate conditional probabilities for values of both lists, bases on their indices. I do (list1 is the input):

list1 = as.numeric(as.vector(list1))
nvalues = length(sort(unique(list1)))
order.list.l1 = sort(unique(list1))
   for(i in 1:nvalues){
        l1 = order.list.l1[i]
           finallist1[[i]] <- which(list1==l1)

I do the same for list2 then I calculate size of values and intersect of values in order to get conditional probabilities.
The thing is, it was running good until I added some NA values.

Answer (score 0):

This code contains several errors:

First off, a vector cannot normally contain `NULL` values at all. Are you maybe using a `list`?

```
if vector=="NULL"
```

you probably mean `if (vector[i] == "NULL")`. Even so, that’s wrong. You cannot filter for `NULL` by comparing to the character string `"NULL"` – those two are fundamentally different things. You need to use the function `is.null` instead. Or, if you’re working with an actual vector which contains NA values (not `NULL`, like I said, that’s not possible), something like `is.na`.

```
i=i+1
```

This code makes no sense – leaving it out won’t change the result because the *loop* is in charge of incrementing `i`.

Finally, don’t iterate over indices – `for (i in 1 : length(x))` is bad style in R. Instead, iterate over the elements directly:

```
for (x in vector) {
    if (! is.na(x)) {
        Perform action
    }
}
```

But even this isn’t very R like. Instead, you would do two things:

1. use subsetting to get rid of `NA` values:

   ```
   vector[! is.na(vector)]
   ```
2. Use one of the [`*apply` functions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lapply.html) (for instance, `sapply`) instead of a loop, and put the loop body into a function:

   ```
   sapply(vector[! is.na(vector)], function (x) Do something with x)
   ```

Comment: Thanks. You´re rights. Those are lists. I will check out apply functions.